# Slider changes web audio gain but can still hear audio

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Doing mozilla tutorial. Volume doesn't go down when I move slider even though gainNode.gain.value goes to zero.

HTML

```
<input type="range" id="volume" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="0.01">

<audio src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3" crossorigin="anonymous" id="basic-audio"></audio>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volume');

const audioElement = document.getElementById('basic-audio');

const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

const audioContext = new AudioContext();

const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

track.connect(audioContext.destination);

const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

track.connect(gainNode).connect(audioContext.destination);

volumeSlider.addEventListener('input', function() {
  gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
  console.log(gainNode.gain.value);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I knew it was a dumb question.

Instead of

```
track.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

and then

```
track.connect(gainNode).connect(audioContext.destination);
```

Just do it once

```
track.connect(gainNode).connect(audioContext.destination);
```

Answer (score -1):

From the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode),

> The GainNode interface represents a change in volume

Since your range is from 0 to 2, that means the change is from 0 to 2. If you want to reduce the sound, you need to apply negative values.

Try changing your input to:

```
<input type="range" id="volume" min="-1" max="2" value="1" step="0.01">
```

Comment: This is wrong.  A gain of 0 produces an output of 0, i.e., silence.  A gain of -1 will just invert the signal, basically preserving the same loudness.